# Bibliotecas de órdenes de Calc de LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Saludos a la comunidad: Soy usuario de LibreOffice Calc (versión 7.0.5.2) y deseo saber en cual biblioteca y archivo se encuentran las codificaciones que corresponden a las distintas órdenes y funciones de Calc (fecha, cadena, matemáticas, lógicas, etc.) tanto las que se colocan en las celdas como las que corresponden al LibreOffice Basic. No he podido encontrar esa información, aun teniendo el libro de Andrew Pitonyak. Agradezco la colaboración.

Comment: ¿Te refieres al código fuente?

Comment: Esta publicación no se ajusta a Cómo preguntar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, recomiendo hagas el recorrido: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: En efecto Ariadna, a eso me refiero. Para ponerlo en ejemplos: si tengo en Calc la función DIAS(Argumento 1; Argumento 2; Argumento 3), ¿donde (ruta y archivo) está la codificación de esta función?. Igual podría decir donde están las codificaciones que procesan las órdenes de LibreOffice Basic (por ejemplo DateDiff)

Comment: Este es el repositorio de [LibreOffice](https://github.com/LibreOffice), pero sin ánimo de asustarte, examinar el código de una aplicación como LibreOffice no es una tarea fácil. Por qué no modificas tu pregunta para saber que es lo quieres lograr o porqué necesitas esta información.

Comment: Hola Ariadna: Me basta con tu respuesta. Simplemente, quería saberlo. Por supuesto, que dentro de ese código debe haber un área en la cual los nombres originales en inglés de las funciones para celdas son traducidos según las convenciones que regían desde Lotus 1-2-3 para D.O.S. (es decir TODAY() equivale a HOY(), etc.). Gracias mil por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

*Del comentario de arriba de Ariadna Cortéz:*

> [Este es el repositorio de LibreOffice](https://github.com/LibreOffice), pero sin ánimo de asustarte, examinar el código de una aplicación como LibreOffice no es una tarea fácil.